# REST WebService with Spring Boot with SSL, but without a self signed certificate

Tags: spring-boot, ssl

I was able to use a REST WebService with Spring Boot with SSL, just like it explains here:

https://medium.com/quick-code/spring-boot-how-to-secure-rest-api-with-https-54ec8f0e4796

But this article shows how to do it generating a self-signed certificate:

```
keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias tutorial -keystore tutorial.jks -storepass password -validity 365 -keysize 4096 -storetype pkcs12
```

Now I have a certificate from a CA, and I have 3 files:

```
private.key
certificate.crt
ca_bundle.crt
```

How can I configure the service to use this SSL certificate, instead of using a self-signed certificate?

Any help/advice would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to follow the same steps highlighted in the article, with the exception that you can generate a keystore from your certificate as follows:
`keytool -import -alias myAlias -file certificate.crt -keystore keystore.p12 -storetype PKCS12 -storepass password`